# Probability of hitting "1" in an array.

Tags: probability

We have an array of length m, where half of the entries in the array are labeled "1" and the rest "0". What is the probability of hitting 3  "1's" in 3 tries?

I believe it should be 0.5 * 0.5 * 0.5 which is 0.125, but I am unsure if I am correct. I essentially just used the probability of hitting a "1" as 0.5 as we know half of the array is filled with "1", and since we have 3 tries it should be 0.5 for each try.
Any help/hints would be appreciated.

Comment: If it's three distinct ones, then hitting a one again after already hitting a one has a lower probability than a half. You can either consider this as a tree or you can consider the ones as distinct and use a counting argument.

Comment: Oh my bad, it shouldn't be 3 distinct "1's"

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct. If you choose the array location independently "at random" each time your experiment is just like flipping a coin three times.

If once you have hit a $1$ you can't hit that spot again then $m$ must be at least $6$ and must be even. Then the probability for three $1$'s in three tries would be
$$
\frac{m/2}{m}\frac{m/2 -1}{m-1}\frac{m/2 -2}{m-2}.
$$
For $m=6$ that's just $1/20$.

(From the start you should be writing your probabilities as fractions: $1/2$ instead of $0.5$. The meaning is clearer and it's easier to do the work when you encounter probabilities like $1/3$.)

Comment: For completeness: $\frac{m-4}{8(m-1)}$

Answer (score 1):

I advise you, each time it is possible, to look for a classical distribution. This will help you a lot in the future when dealing with more complex probability issues.

Here you have a random variable $S$ (number of successes in 3 trials) following a **Binomial distribution** $$B(n=3,p=\frac12)$$

because it is a repeated experiment you do $n=3$ times independently, each time  with a probability of success $p=\tfrac12$.

The probability of $S$ "successes" are distributed in this way (with $q=1-p$):

$$P(S=0)=q^3, \ \ P(S=1)=3pq^2, \ \ P(S=2)=3p^2q, \ \ P(S=3)=p^3$$

(please note that the sum $q^3+3pq^2+3p^2q+p^3=(p+q)^3=1$ involving the binomial expansion, explaining the name of the distribution).

You are in the fourth case (3 "successes" in 3 attempts), giving you indeed

$$P(S=3)=p^3=\tfrac18=0.125$$